# django: pasting text of a pdf file gathered using choose file button in a textarea

Tags: python, django, templates, textarea

I am new to Django and currently, I am working on a website where I have a choose file button and a text area. I want that when I click on the choose file button and choose a .txt or .pdf file, all the text from that file has to show in the textarea alongside it. here is the GUI
[here is the look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2TWy.png)
but this thing is not working.
I have tried a lot of solutions but nothing is working for me. I am using python version 3.8 and Django version 3.1
here is the models.py

```
class text_file(models.Model):

txtfile = models.FileField()
text = models.TextField(max_length=10000)
date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True) #data saved into db

def __str__(self):
    return self.text_file
```

here is my fileactions.py file. It's a model form.

```
from PyPDF2 import pdf, PdfFileReader
from django import forms
from .models import text_file


class filetext(forms.ModelForm):
text_file = forms.FileField(required=True, widget=forms.Textarea(
    attrs={
        'class': 'form-control',
        'placeholder': 'text_file...',
        'id': 'input1'
    }
))


class Meta:
    model = text_file #import text_file model from home models.py
    fields = {'text_file'} 

def save(self, commit=True):
    filename = input('file')
    textfile = open(filename, 'rb')
    pdf_reader = pdf.PdfFileReader(textfile)

    page_numbers = pdf_reader.getNumPages()
    title = pdf_reader.documentInfo.title
    print("the document title is: ", title)
    print("there are total: ", page_numbers, "pages")
    count = 0
    text = ''
    while count < page_numbers:
        page = pdf_reader.getPage(count)
        text += page.extractText()
        return self.text 
    return super().save(commit)
```

home.html

```
<div id="intro">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4">
     <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data", id='textForm' method="post"/> 
     {% csrf_token %} 
     {{ form.as_p }} 
     </form> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
                       
    </div>
    <input type="file" class="btn btn-primary" Text="choose file" id="file"><br>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

view.py

```
def post_text(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    form = filetext(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        text = form.cleaned_data.get('text_file')
        return render(request=request,
                      template_name="main/home.html.html",
                      context={"form": form})

form = filetext
return render(request=request,
              template_name="main/home.html",
              context={"form": form})
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
         path("filetext", views.post_text, name="homepage"),
       ]
```

please help me either with your suggestions on this code or with your own code example. (if someone does the same thing)

Comment: If you simply intend to display the contents of the file in a textbox- there's a much easier way to do so using JavsScript/jQuery. Simply open the file and once the user selects it, use some JS library to parse and read the file. You can then subsequently apply the read contents to the textbox.

Comment: actually, my intention is to perform other operations on that file. It's all about NLP using python. That file is uploaded by other users who come to this site, not by me. I want to extract the text of this file, show its text in the textarea and then perform NLP operations on the text.

Comment: What is your exact error? Can you give at least the error trace for me to look into it?

Comment: there is no error. when I click on the button choose file, it prompts me to select the file, when I select file its name shows at the button replacing the text 'no file chosen'. but nothing happens after it.  its text did not appear in the textarea.

Comment: AzyCrw4282 please help me with your knowledge. I am doing my semester project and I need to resolve this as soon as possible.

Comment: I would love to help but I am afraid, I really can't guess where the error may be stemming from. To locate the errors from Django projects involve me setting up my env and testing the project which is such a cumbersome task. Without any error trace I really cant be of any help. I would advice you to search around and see if there's any other solutions that exist to overcome this problem.

Comment: I am searching around already and tried another one. but now it gives me an error 'template does not exist at/'. I don't know why this Django is so annoying and confusing.